mat-slide-toggle is not disabling in Angular 15 but works fine in Angular 14 with same code
I updated to Angular 15 and now [disabled] attribute of mat-slide-toggle is not working well.
The top toggle should be disabled at startup, but now it only becomes disabled after being manually turned off and then turned back on.
I created 2 examples in stackblitz with the same code:
Here it works well:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zpxbxf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
and here is not:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-15-starter-pack-cpnrr2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
I solved this problem with workarounds, but I would still like to know what the problem is and why it doesn't work as expected

The console has a warning. When using reactive forms, you should not use the disabled attribute. The reason why it's different after the Angular 15 update is probably the MDC migration

@JSON_Derulo in MDC migration they write about mat-slide-toggle: "@angular/material/slide-toggle: Style changes only". So, in a theory nothing should be changed after update. Using the disabled attribute also wasn't recommended in A14 and even in A6, but in A14 it is working well (see my first link).

Below they say about the slide toggle: "To improve accessibility, the MDC-based version uses  to represent the toggle rather than . Slide toggle will no longer respond to native form validation. Consider alternative approaches to form validation."
